# VBA find and replace

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I am using the code below, to do a find and replace on excel:

```
Sub abbrev()
Dim abvtab() As Variant
Dim ltsheet As Worksheet
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim lt As Range
Dim i As Long
Set ltsheet = Sheets("sheet2")
' REFERENCE TO SINGLE WORKSHEET
'  Set datasheet = Sheets("ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_User")
Set lt = ltsheet.Range("A2", ltsheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown))
abvtab = lt
For Each datasheet In Worksheets
If datasheet.Name <> ltsheet.Name Then
For i = 1 To UBound(abvtab)
datasheet.Cells.Replace What:=abvtab(i, 1), Replacement:=abvtab(i, 2), 
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Next i
End If
Next datasheet
End Sub
```

However it doesn't seem to be able to find parts of the words for example if I want to replace the word book the code ignores the word bookshelves

Is there a way I can set the code above to match the exact word regardless if its part of a sentence or if it has a space for example?

Comment: I also tried to change LookAt:=xlPart to LookAt:=xlWhole but didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: The replacement code works just fine when I test it. Are you sure the range that you're filling `abvtab` from is correct?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any spaces or other invisible characters in the cells you read for your find?

Comment: thank you for looking into it, the cells i am replacing or the ones i am referencing to all have spaces and possibly invisible characters, I am trying to get the code to isolate the words whatever they may be, when using one cell to replace it seems to work fine but when replacing multiple rows and sheets it appears to be selective and changes words from Iron Man to something like *** Man even though the search word is Iron Man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end I had to abandon vba and instead I used C# Regex.Replace there was many issues with the find and replace via excel so the solution below seemed to work well, although the below worked i also had to abandon it as csv was the wrong file format for what i needed I'll be using mysql instead, i pasted the code below either way just in case someone might benefit from it and use it to do find and replace at scale

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string SAR_CONTACTS = @"C: \Users\Desktop\SAR_CONTACTS.csv";
string SAR_CONTENT = @"C: \Users\Desktop\SAR_CONTENT.csv";
string READ_SAR_CONTACTS;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(SAR_CONTENT, Encoding.UTF8))
READ_SAR_CONTACTS = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

string SAR_CONTACTS_FILE = File.ReadAllText(SAR_CONTACTS);
string SAR_CONTENT_FILE = SAR_CONTACTS_FILE.Replace("\r\n", "|");
SAR_CONTENT_FILE = SAR_CONTENT_FILE.Remove(SAR_CONTENT_FILE.Length - 1);
string SAR_CONTENT_CENSORED = Regex.Replace(READ_SAR_CONTACTS, SAR_CONTENT_FILE, 
 "######", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
File.WriteAllText(@"C: \Users\Desktop\SAR_CONTENT_FILTERED.csv", 
 SAR_CONTENT_CENSORED);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("*" & "Ca" & "*", "United States", "Mexico")
rplcList = Array("CAN", "USA", "MEX")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Notice the wildcard characters: `"*" & "Ca" & "*"`

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]